# React/Redux/Router integration error: "React.createElement: type is invalid"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

Trying to learn the React/Redux/React Router ecosystem and running into an issue now that I'm trying to integrate React Router.

I've tried lowering the versions of React Router and History to 2.X.X but that didn't help.

Getting the error "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in."

How can I determine which object is undefined?

PS: I know this isn't set up ideally in terms of using Webpack and imports but I'm trying to get an understanding of the components before learning these other components.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Redux Route Test</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.6.0/redux.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/5.0.3/react-redux.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/4.1.1/react-router.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-redux/4.0.8/ReactRouterRedux.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/history/4.5.1/history.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content" id="content">

        </div>
        <script type="text/babel">
            const initialState = {
                items: []
            }

            function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
                switch(action.type) {
                    case 'GET_ALL':
                        return Object.assign({}, state, {items: action.items});
                    case 'ADD_NEW':
                        return Object.assign({}, state, {items: [...state.items, action.item]});
                    default:
                        return state;
                }
            }

            const history = History.createBrowserHistory();
            const middleware = ReactRouterRedux.routerMiddleware(history);

            const store = Redux.createStore(
                Redux.combineReducers({
                    ...reducer,
                    router: ReactRouterRedux.routerReducer
                }),
                Redux.applyMiddleware(middleware)
            );

            class ContainerA extends React.Component {
                load() {
                    var json = [
                        {fieldA: "1", fieldB: "2"},
                        {fieldA: "3", fieldB: "4"}
                    ]

                    store.dispatch({type: 'GET_ALL', items: json});
                }

                render() {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <button onClick={this.load.bind(this)}>Load Data</button>
                            <label>{this.props.items.length}</label>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            }

            class ContainerB extends React.Component {
                render() {
                    return (
                        <div>Loaded Next Component</div>
                    )
                }
            }

            const mapStateToProps = function(store) {
                return {
                    items: store.items
                }
            }

            var RootApp = ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps)(ContainerA);

            ReactDOM.render(
                <ReactRedux.Provider store={store}>
                    <ReactRouterRedux.ConnectedRouter>
                        <ReactRouter.Route path="/" component={RootApp} />
                    </ReactRouterRedux.ConnectedRouter>
                </ReactRedux.Provider>,
                document.getElementById("content")
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't try to learn all these techs at once. Unless you have a business need for `redux` you can use React's state management system (i.e. `setState`). Same goes for the router, only add these pieces in when you have a need.

Comment: That most likely is an issue where you're attempting to render a component that is undefined or null.